# Retrieval of Word Score from mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, mysql-workbench

I want to retrieve a score of words from databse  and then  I will make a decision about paragraph that this is positive paragraph or negative paragraph
The **database file format** is like this. where some key word  have positive and negative score

```
Word                Pos_Score           Neg_Score

Able                .324                .834
Country             .987                .213
Love                .378                .734 
agree               .546                .123
industry            .289                .714
guests              .874                .471
```

The **Paragraph** will be like this.

```
I agree with you.  It seems an intelligent tourist industry allows its guests to either immerse fully, in part, or not, depending upon the guest.  That is why the ugly American charges have always confused me.
```

Now I will compare each word of the paragraph with database  file if the word found in the database file then I will retrieve the Pos_Scoe and Neg_Score score of word and these score will be store in  variable when the whole paragraph will compare   at the end Pos_Score will add separately and the Neg_Score will add separately . and this will be the result.
**Code** that i try is this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string MyConString = "server=localhost;" +
                   "database=sentiwornet;" + "password=zia;" +
                   "User Id=root;";
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                MySqlDataReader Reader;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:\\input.txt");
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

                    foreach (string part in parts)
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT Pos_Score FROM score WHERE Word = 'part'";
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT Neg_Score FROM score WHERE Word = 'part'";
                        //var 
                        connection.Open();
                        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Approximately how many words are in your database?

Comment: @rmayer06: 32,000 words will be in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this query promises to be horribly inefficient.  Instead, if your paragraphs are small enough, I would execute all of the joins inside the database by passing in the arguments as a CSV-list, then converting to a table in SQL.  The following function will do that (courtesy of http://codebank.wordpress.com/2007/03/06/simple-sql-csv-to-table-2/):

**Caveat:** you will need to strip all punctuation out using something like `string.Replace(new[] { '.', ',' ... etc })`

Also, it's possible that my code doesn't do exactly what you want - it may not even compile - but that is the joy of programming. This gives you the general idea I have on how to solve a rather complex problem.

**Edit:**  I just realized you are using MySql. This code would work for MSSQL - I have never used MySql from the CLR, so I don't know if all of the classes are equivalent. You may need to go back to what you were doing before.

#### CSV to List

```
Create Function dbo.fn_CSVToTable (@CSVList Varchar(MAX))
Returns @Table Table (ColumnData Varchar(50))
As
Begin
If right(@CSVList, 1) <> ','
Select @CSVList = @CSVList + ','

Declare @Pos    Smallint,
@OldPos Smallint
Select  @Pos    = 1,
@OldPos = 1

While   @Pos < Len(@CSVList)
Begin
Select  @Pos = CharIndex(',', @CSVList, @OldPos)
Insert into @Table
Select  LTrim(RTrim(SubString(@CSVList, @OldPos, @Pos - @OldPos))) Col001
Select  @OldPos = @Pos + 1
End

Return
End
```

#### SQL Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetWordScores (@csv varchar(MAX))
AS
select POS_SCORE, NEG_SCORE, WORD from score
inner join dbo.fn_CSVToTable(@csv) input
    on input.ColumnData = score.WORD
```

#### New C# Code

```
var MyConString = "server=localhost;" +
               "database=sentiwornet;" + "password=zia;" +
               "User Id=root;";
var connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);

//Each line in the array will probably be one paragraph.
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\input.txt");
foreach (var line in fileLines)
{
        //Format your line into words by removing punctuation. I'm not going to bother
        //with that code because it is trivial.
        //var csv = line.Split(' ');

        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "exec spGetWordScores";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csv", csv);
        var ds = command.ExecuteDataSet();

        //Now you have a DataSet with your word scores. do with them what you will.
}
```

#### Helpful Extension Method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now Zia can just copy-paste all this, not fair :)

Comment: Well, just trying to be thorough! Some of it admittedly came from my own code libraries as I do stuff like this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Going back and forward to the database is going to kill your performance. Best to write a stored procedure that takes in your input string, splits it and calculates the score - this way all of the processing will happen on one machine and you will save significant time by not communicating partial results.

Comment: Garvil: Sir if you send me the code or send a correct code of my requirement